# Complexity of double-nested loop

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment as a function of N?

```
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*4)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            { cnt++; }
```

I now for example that first loop execute ~`log(4, N)` times and the second loop execute ~`N` times. But how to combine this knowlege to find the answer?

What is the general way to find that kind of complexity?
Maybe, we need to know how much time the body of the inner loop is executed?
For example `1 + 4 + 16 + 64 + ... + N`

Comment: did you not answer this just now?  N * Log(4,N)   removing constants is:  nlog(n)

Comment: Why did you use multiplying?

Comment: @Fallenreaper  `1 + 4 + 16 + 64 + ... + N` it is not `N * Log(4,N)` . I think the answer is `N`

Comment: @Anatoly the series is a geometric progression, which does sum to `O(N)`.  Or, if `N` is a power of 4, then it sums to exactly `(4 N - 1) / 3`.

Comment: @AdeelZafarSoomro Maybe you know how to prove that the series is equal to ~`(4/3)N`. I found that answer in the algo book.

Comment: This geometric series has `ceiling(Log(4, N + 1))` terms, 1 as its first term and a common ratio of 4.  Using the geometric series formula yields the above result if we allow the following approximation: `4 ^ ceiling(Log(4, N + 1))` ~ `N`.

Comment: @Anatoly We know the series is a geometric progression. [We also know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) what the sum of an arbitrary geometric progression is. That's enough to make a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometric progression = `(x^n - 1)/(x-1)` where `n=Log(4,N)`, so the result is

`(x^log(x, N) - 1)/ (x-1) = (4N - 1)/3`

Answer (score -1):

Let's N belong to the interval [4^k; 4^(k+1)), then we have got sum:

sum 4^i, i=0..k = (4^(k+1)-1)/3 = O(n)

I was late some minutes and minus...